# How to put welcome "username" after login in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a login form built in Microsoft Access. The User will login through it and make it to the main page form.

**How do we put the Welcome "Username" (e.g. Welcome John) on the main page form?**

I also want to mention about the database - I have the table with Username and Password as the columns.

The table were accessed during the login session.

Do we use Expression Builder? How will the codes look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a Global or Public variable in a standard module.

When the user clicks the login button, and before the login screen closes, set the variable to the value of the username.

Create a public function that returns the value of the variable.

Then create a text box on your form that has the function name in the control source!

I'm sorry, I can't give you any demo code since you don't show what you have tried. If you can show what you have tried we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me a vision of how to do it. I should have posted a coding sample too.

Comment: Erm, @Freeman Helmuth, any idea where should I write the function to return the value of global variable? In the module OR login page form OR or main page form?

Comment: In the same module that you declare the variable, it really doesn't matter which module, as long as it is a standard module

Comment: Alhamdulillah, thanks @Freeman, it works! I'm not familiar with the VBA Function and that what makes me stuck like idiot.

Comment: Something like this: Public Function GetUser()

Comment: Then in the function put: GetUser = pUsername. ( or whatever the name of your variable is)